# ExportAsFixedFormat change to idividual pages

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-pdf

I am using this code below to save specific tabs to PDF and has been working great.

Now I need it to do the same but save each Tab into a separate page. Currently all tabs go into 1 PDF.

```
Sub print_shipping_tabs()
'
' print_shipping_tabs Macro
' Prints the Shipping Tabs Only
'
'
    Sheets(Array("Shipping", "Shipping (CO1)", "Shipping (CO2)", "Shipping (CO3)", "Shipping (CO4)", "Shipping (CO5)", "Shipping (CO6)", "Shipping (CO7)", "Shipping (CO8)", "Shipping (CO9)")).Select
    Sheets("Shipping").Activate
'Save Active Sheet(s) as PDF
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Worksheets("Job Notice").Range("S1"), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Sheets("Job Notice").Activate
End Sub
```